# Java groupingBy is always changing order

Tags: java, list, java-stream, grouping, collectors

i have List with simple object:

```
private String unit;
private Double value;
```

List looks like that:

```
f, 1.0;
ml, 15.0;
g, 9.0
```

I have created a simple function where I want to group this values and put them to the map with unit as a key, and list of objects as value, but I want to save the order like in my original list. This is my current solution:

```
myList.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(MyObject::getUnit));
```

But after that my map is sorted alphabetically this way:
f, g, ml  instead of f, ml, g.
Is there any alternative for groupingBy to fix it?

Comment: The "alphabetic" order is coincidence, the hashcodes of "f" and "g" indeed being ordered (same length).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is that `groupingBy` puts things into some map, probably a `HashMap`, which has no guaranteed ordering.

Use the [`groupingBy` overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) which takes a `Supplier<M> mapFactory`, to get a map with an ordering guarantee, e.g.

```
myList.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(MyObject::getUnit,
                        LinkedHashMap::new,
                        Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Though here the OP seems to want `LinkedHashMap::new`.

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc for [groupingBy()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) says:

> There are **no** guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the Map or List objects returned.

And then, the Map interface itself doesn't give **any** guarantee about the order of keys!

Thus: you either have to use another *grouping* method (that allows you to force a `LinkedHashMap` or a `TreeMap`), or to step back, and to rethink your whole approach. You could for example **sort** your list after it was pulled together.